# Android Error: Window Leaked in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, memory-leaks

I have only sometimes an error which says `Activity com.prueba.omnibus.EspacialTecnico has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41e794a0 that was originally added here`
This happens when the activity finishes and an asynctask function is executed. I have searched but I have no idea what the problem could be.

Action that is doen when the user clicks "finish" and the error happens.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    super.onCreateDialog(id);
    switch (id) {
    case (int) DIALOG_ALERT_SALIR:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_warning)
                .setTitle(R.string.warning)
                .setMessage(R.string.confsalir)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                if (batteryReceiver == null){   
                                }
                                else{
                                    try{
                                        unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
                                    }catch(IllegalArgumentException iae){
                                    }
                                    batteryReceiver = null;
                                }           



                               Correccion();
                               Parseo();
                               reloj.cancel();
                               if (Titulacion.IsReachable1(getApplicationContext())){
                                new CreateResultados().execute();


                                }
                               EspacialTecnico.this.finish();
                               try {
                                    XMLResumen.escribirXMLResume();
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }}


                       })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                            }
                        })

                .create();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Asynctask Function
Could the error be produced by the dialog?

```
class CreateResultados extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EspacialTecnico.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Transfiriendo...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Ident.getDNI()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", Nombres.getNombre()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tablet", Nombres.Tablet()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fecha", Titulacion.fecha()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", nombre));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("correctas", correctasString));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("errores", fallosString));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PC", PC));



            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_crear_resultados,
                    "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());


            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {


                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }



        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Is there anything "bad" done? Thanks for the help

Comment: apart form the ansewers you are missing @Override annotation for `onPostExecute` and `super.onPostExecute`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception usually comes from dialogs that are still active when the activity is finishing.

In `onPreExecute()` you create a new dialog but it might be so that `pDialog` already holds a reference to an active dialog. Some ways around it:

- Check for `pDialog == null` before creating a new one. Assign a `null` to `pDialog` after dismissing it.
- If `pDialog != null`, `dismiss()` it first before creating a new dialog.

(Also `super.onCreateDialog()` is unnecessary as you're not doing anything with the returned `Dialog`.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation, Could be another alternative to remove the dialog?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is in

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

If your touch the dialog box after your activity is finish, an expection is raise. You have to be carefull, when your activity is finish the asynctask continue and postexecute is called.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in post Execute:

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    if (pDialog.isShowing()){
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                }
```

Its working for me.