# How to parse JSON from URL with unnamed array

Tags: android, json, parsing

Sorry for my newbie question, but please tell me what I do wrong. I'm trying to parse JSON from URL which contains such strings as :

> [{"Date":"25","Time":"10:00","Place":"","Text":"\u0414\u041e\u0411\u0420\u041e
>   \u041f\u041e\u0416\u0410\u041b\u041e\u0412\u0410\u0422\u042c \u0412
>   \u00ab\u041f\u0410\u0420\u041a
>   \u0414\u0417\u042e\u0414\u041e\u00bb!"},{"Date":"25","Time":"10:00","Place":"\u041a\u0440\u044b\u0448\u0430
>   \u041b\u0410
>   \u00ab\u0422\u0420\u0410\u041a\u0422\u041e\u0420\u00bb","Text":"Open-Air:
>   \u0432\u0430\u0441
>   \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u0435\u0442
>   \u043e\u0444\u0438\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439
>   \u0434\u0438-\u0434\u0436\u0435\u0439 \u041f\u0430\u0440\u043a\u0430
>   \u0414\u0417\u042e\u0414\u041e DJ \u0420\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d
>   \u041a\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0435\u0446"}]

As you can see this is an JSON array with no name and with objects inside. So how can I parse it to show in my ListView? What I do :

```
public class NewsActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://mysitehere.com/news.php";

// JSON Node names

private static final String TAG_DATE = "Date";
private static final String TAG_TIME = "Time";
private static final String TAG_PLACE = "Place";
private static final String TAG_TEXT = "Text";;


// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AfishaList;

protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_activity);

    new GetInfo().execute();
}

private class GetInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("LOG_TAG","PROGRESS STARTS");
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < mJSONArray.length(); i++) {

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject e = mJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_DATE, e.getString("Date"));
                    contact.put(TAG_TIME, e.getString("Time"));
                    contact.put(TAG_PLACE, e.getString("Place"));
                    contact.put(TAG_TEXT, e.getString("Text"));

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    AfishaList.add(contact);
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG","SOMETHING IS GOING ON");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                NewsActivity.this, AfishaList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_DATE, TAG_TIME,
                TAG_PLACE, TAG_TEXT }, new int[] { R.id.date,
                R.id.time, R.id.place, R.id.text });

       setListAdapter(adapter);
        Log.w("FINAL","!!!");
    }

}
```

}

**EDIT:**

I've changed the method in `doInBackground` and now `logcat` shows me the following log:

```
 07-31 10:05:35.682    3920-3934/com.project1.2014 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.project1.2014.NewsActivity$GetInfo.doInBackground(NewsActivity.java:110)
        at com.project1.2014.NewsActivity$GetInfo.doInBackground(NewsActivity.java:65)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: refer this- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164741/get-jsonarray-without-array-name

Comment: Add your logcat error/info .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your response first element is a `JSON Array` not `JSON Object`. Thats why you are getting `JSON Exception`. From your code remove this line

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

After do that if you will get any exception or crash post `logcat`.

**EDIT : 1**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                NewsActivity.this, AfishaList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_DATE, TAG_TIME,
                TAG_PLACE, TAG_TEXT }, new int[] { R.id.date,
                R.id.time, R.id.place, R.id.text });

       setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }
```

try this code for `onPostExecute(...)` and if you show any other `Dialog` dismiss that. That will cause [Windowleak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added).Clean your project then run it.

- [Android Error: Window Leaked in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155670/android-error-window-leaked-in-asynctask)

**Edit : 2**
Line no 110 of `NewsActivity` is `AfishaList.add(contact);`  so create Object of AfishaList before accessing it.

Comment: I've updated my question again

Comment: I m guessing line no `110` of `NewsActivity` is `AfishaList.add(contact);` if so create `Object` of `AfishaList` before accessing it.

Comment: welcome glad 2 help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first tag is `JSON ARRAY` so just remove this.

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Comment: I've updated my question with logcat

Comment: if GetInfo class is in activity class??